# 404 error for static assets when browser caching is implemented with nginx/web2py

Tags: caching, nginx, web2py, uwsgi

I have a web2py configuration, operating on top of nginx, which is producing a 404 error when browser caching is implemented for certain static files. The problem is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/840207/404-error-for-static-assets-when-browser-caching-implemented-on-nginx), and I'm now asking this question within a web2py context, because that may be relevant to the issue, or because there may be some web2py-specific workaround or solution.

nginx.conf looks like this:

```
worker_processes  3;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log  [/...];
    error_log   [/...]  crit;

    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        server_name [...] [...];
        return 301 [...] $request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:[...];
        root [/...];

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the following line either before or after the "location" clause above causes the server to stop serving the static files, which match the pattern in question:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1d;
}
```

It was suggested in the previous thread that this may be a uwsgi issue, although it's possible that the problem is caused by other issues. How can I implement browser caching, without causing the "404" issue?

Comment: Try adding the lines `include uwsgi_params; uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];` to the new location block.

Comment: @RichardSmith - Thank you. After double-checking, I'm reasonably sure that it works (although, after dealing with this for the last couple of hours, I'm half-expecting something to get screwed up again). If you'd like to put that down as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are serving only dynamic content. Also, `nginx` selects a `location` block to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), and it needs to be complete.

In your case, the `uwsgi` configuration from the `location /` block needs to be replicated across any new dynamic locations you may add. For example:

```
server {
    ...

    include uwsgi_params;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 1d;
        uwsgi_pass [.../uwsgi.sock];
    }
}
```

You can probably move the `include` statement into the outer block and allow its statements to be inherited (assuming it only contains `uwsgi_param` statements).

Comment: I tried to use browser cache for 404 errors and I have found few weird scenarios. When I type in the URL "testsite.com/testblabla.png", we are getting an 404 response with e-tag and when I refresh the same browser tab it is not using the browser cache where as If I open the same url in a new tab it is getting from browser cache. It is so weird, also firefox is not using the browser cache for 404 status at all. Guys, please let me know if you also face the same issues